# Phonegap Android "navigator.notification.activitystart()" in tablets

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

In my Android application, I am using Phonegap's `navigator.notification.activitystart()` event to show the `Activity` indicator. It is working fine in Android phones and tablets, but the problem is when I touch the screen of the tablet, the loader disappears even if the loading is not finished.

How can I prevent the disappearance of loading indicator when I touch on the screen using `javascript/jquery`?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you could change that implementation using javascript alone.  The way PhoneGap works is that it will create an object ProgressDialog in the native Android code.  I think the issue is that it is setting the ProgressDialog to cancelable in its constructor.  If you go into the cordova source code you could change that and it should create a fix for your specific issue.

Source code from Notification.java lines 250-255 change the second true to false

```
Notification.this.spinnerDialog = ProgressDialog.show(cordova.getActivity(), title, message, true, true/*change this to false*/,
                        new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                Notification.this.spinnerDialog = null;
                            }
                        });
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't have notification.java. Shall I create a new one? If I do so and write the code that you have given, which method I have to call in my javascript file, now I am calling navigator.notification.activitystart() when the ajax request is sent and calling navigator.notification.activitystop() when ajax request stops. How can I do this with your code?

Comment: OK well you can start using the source code instead of an import for the phonegap library, or just create a simple plugin for phonegap that creates a spinner how you would like it.  To create the plugin just take a look at the cordova plugin that exists and maybe cannibalise some of their code.  Here is a link for the source code for that plugin.

https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/Notification.java

Comment: Yes I can add that plugin into my project, then how can I apply that in my javascript. Currently I am having this: $(document).bind("ajaxSend", function() {
       navigator.notification.activityStart(Title,"Loading..");
      }).bind("ajaxStop", function() {
  navigator.notification.activityStop();
     }).bind("ajaxError", function() {
      navigator.notification.activityStop();
    });  How can I modify now?